# Bazel build for TensorFlow inception model

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tensorflow, bazel

I am following tutorial for inception model build for TensorFlow at url (https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/image_retraining/). When I am running command `bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain`, I am getting error:

> The 'build' command is only supported from within a workspace.

I have set up tensorflow using normal `pip install` command and no Docker or Anaconda has been installed to run with TensorFlow. Bazel was set up by brewing and I am on Mac OSX v10.11.x.

Comment: I have my tensorflow env var set as:
TENSORFLOW=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow

Answer (score 13):

First run `touch WORKSPACE`, and then run the `bazel build` command.

Comment: For windows users run the command "touch workspace" from Git Bash

Answer (score 5):

When I did this, I git cloned the directory (git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/) to $HOME/tensorflow, then from the root of the 'tensorflow' directory (the workspace it is referring to), I ran ./configure and then executed "bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain". The output is then generated in a bazel-bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds silly, but I was stuck for 30 seconds before realizing I wasn't calling the right /path/to/cmd

Worth double checking...